# Nginx - Different proxy pass based on ISP

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a dynamic website which shows content regarding on the User searches. Now I want the users, which are coming from specific ISP, send via rproxy to other servers, so I can divide the visitors to different servers.
What is the best method to do this with nginx. I dont want to use the location module, because it is not working like I want it

As example: I want nginx to route the isp from orange to another server, than the isp from AT&T. Both should get a webiste, which are looking different, because the websites are on different servers

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working the way you 'like it'? Be explicit and maybe offer code on how you've tried to solve the problem.

Comment: As example: I want nginx to route the isp from orange to another server, than the isp from AT&T. Both should get a webiste, which are looking different, because the websites are on different servers

Comment: Add that as **Edit:** to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using `geo` module directives.

Define mapping of client IP addresses (or networks) to your backend server IP addresses:

```
geo $backend {
    default 1.2.3.4;
    1.1.1.1/32 100.100.100.101
    2.2.2.2/32 200.200.200.202
}
```

Where:

- first line will set `backend` variable to backend server IP 1.2.3.4
- second line sets `backend` variable to backend server IP 100.100.100.101 if visitors come from network 1.1.1.1/32
- similar to previous, you got the idea already :)

Then you would `proxy_pass` using that variable:

```
location /
    proxy_pass http://$backend;
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I want to check the ISP of the ip first. I had the same idea using geo and location.

Comment: @Tarderd100 wouldn't that  check be same as that `geo` map? Not like you want to actually find ISP NAME of any visitor's IP then use it as variable somewhere.

Comment: Thats the Point, I need to know which ISP he is BEFORE he sees the website